# httpclient with retry and circuit breaker as a additional capability

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, circuit-breaker

I am trying to create httpclient with retry and circuit breaker as a additional capability.

I can add retryhandler to httpcleint like below but not able to add circuitBreaker to httpclient. (I am using java 8)

```
public CloseableHttpClient createClient(){
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setRetryHandler(new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
            log.debug("retryRequest "+executionCount);
            return executionCount <= Constants.MAX_RETRIES ;
        }
    }).build();

    return httpclient;
}
```

any leads on this will be much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I will have to keep my answer brief because I myself interacted with such a problem very recently. One thing that can help you is to make use of ***Hystrix Command Circuit Breaker Pattern***.

It is a library written by Netflix where you can wrap your HTTP calls around a Hystrix command and it helps you to add circuit breaking, fallback functionality among others.

Here is a blog that could be a starter for you: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-cloud/spring-hystrix-circuit-breaker-tutorial/

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal example of this working? Ideally incorporating this into the code posted as part of the question?

Comment: We don't want to use Hystrix for some reasons.  Do we have any similar confirmation for circuitbreaker like retryhandler  I am trying to create httpclient with retry and circuit breaker as a additional capability.

I can add retryhandler to httpcleint like below but not able to add circuitBreaker to httpclient. (I am using java 8)

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setRetryHandler